# Publishing Asp.Net Core MVC Web Apps as Deployment Package or for IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core-1.0

i am having trouble in publishing my ASP.Net Core MVC Web App to IIS.

1. when publishing the app via File System - Publish Method, and hooking the output folder to IIS, i get this error below

[image]

2. when publishing the app via Web Deployment Package - Publish Method, i get this error below

[image]

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"
>
> No executable found matching command "dotnet-publish-iis"

i already have the necessary things installed, that is if i have not missed anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have following lines in your project.json file:

```
"tools": {
  "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
}
```

Comment: seems like this was what is lacking from my project.json file. turns out, i only have `BundlerMinifier.Core`. strange. thanks anyway :)